How to Deserialize a JSON Array into a List of Objects Using IParseNode in C#?
I'm working with the Microsoft Graph API and using the Kiota-generated models. I can successfully deserialize a single Participant entity from JSON using the following code:
IParseNode parseNode = new JsonParseNode(jsonString);
var participant = new Participant();
var fieldDeserializers = participant.GetFieldDeserializers();

foreach (var field in fieldDeserializers)
{
    var propertyParseNode = parseNode.GetChildNode(field.Key);
    if (propertyParseNode != null)
    {
        field.Value(propertyParseNode);
    }
}

However, I need to deserialize a JSON array into a List. I’m unsure how to modify this code to iterate over the array and deserialize each Participant object correctly.
What I have tried:
var participantsNode = parseNode.GetChildNode("participants");

foreach (var childNode in participantsNode.GetChildNode()) //There is no such property available on IParseNode



I would parse JSON string into JsonDocument and then call GetCollectionOfObjectValues on JsonParseNode.
using var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
var rootParseNode = new JsonParseNode(jsonDocument.RootElement);
var participants = rootParseNode.GetCollectionOfObjectValues(Participant.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);

But it depends how your JSON string looks like.

The whole event is actually this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true&tabs=csharp#delta-roster-enabled
I already took out  "resourceData" in the json string. So it is basically an array if you notice.

If it's an array then rootParseNode.GetCollectionOfObjectValues(Participant.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue); should work. You can also try var participants= rootParseNode.GetObjectValue(DeltaParticipants.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
